I can't put a plug into a new TR Leviton GFCI outlet
There seems to be white plastic blocking the holes preventing a plug from being plugged into the outlet. The ground holes are open but the straight holes are blocked.

What type of plug are you trying to use? Is it one with a ground pin or without? If without, are you able to plug in something that does have a ground pin in the plug?

@BartvanIngenSchenau -- the NEMA TR design isn't dependent on a ground pin being present.  (NEMA 1 plugs are still legal in the US, and show up all the time on double-insulated gear here)

@ThreePhaseEel, I just wanted to rule out that it is a tamper-resistant design that triggers on the ground pin. But such a design could be a UK specific thing.

@BartvanIngenSchenau  Such a design is definitely UK-specific, or at least nonexistent in the US. Plugs with no ground are very common here, for the same sort of double-insulated equipment where British plugs would have a plastic "ground" pin, and if new plugs suddenly required a ground pin for mechanical actuation, no one would use them despite the safety benefits because 70% of their stuff wouldn't be possible to plug in anymore without going to the hassle of replacing the plug (which also isn't nearly as trivial in the US as it is in the UK).

Based on your calling this a "GFCI" and not an "RCBO", I deduce you're in North America.
There's probably a "TR" stamped on the outlet or on the instruction sheet or box the outlet came in. This means it's "tamper resistant". The white flaps keep folks from putting metal objects in the slots unless they're putting two metal objects in at the same time, exactly aligned so the same pressure from the two objects hits the white flaps exactly at the same time and in the same force. Such a special alignment is usually possible with a standard undamaged plug, but it can be a bit tricky until you get the action right.
This means you have to put the plug in straight in, not at a slight angle like non-tamper-resistant outlets would allow.
Go straight in with the plug, at a 90-degree right angle to the outlet face, and the plug should go in.

This is a tamper-resistant receptacle, which is generally required for new installations under the NEC. The way it should work is that if you press straight in with both prongs (hot and neutral) at the same time that some sort of spring-loaded mechanism should let the plug go in. If you press just one at a time, it won't, so if you push in at an angle it is quite possible that it just won't work. If it doesn't work after carefully trying "straight in" then it may be broken.
Note that the ground pin is not relevant here for several reasons:

There are plenty of commonly available ungrounded devices - cell phone chargers, some small appliances, even some "double insulated" tools.
Ground is virtually always safe. If properly wired, or even with the most common mistake (hot/neutral reverse), ground is still ground and perfectly safe to touch, so it doesn't need tamper protection.

There is an unfortunately common problem, particularly with poorly done non-electrician (handyman or DIY) work, of hot/neutral reverse. That should never happen, not just because it is against code but because it is trivially easy to detect and correct at installation time using a "magic 8-ball" 3-light tester, such as this Klein from Amazon:

If everyone tested before closing up the installation, there would never be a hot/neutral reverse. In ye olden times it could happen more easily because (a) these testers were not as common and (b) if there is no ground available at all then this type of tester doesn't work. But that has not been the case in the GFCI era, so there is no excuse. But it still happens.
However, the chance of ground actually being hot is extremely small - I think it would require three mistakes to produce a nominally functional receptacle and also have a hot ground: hot/neutral reverse and neutral/ground connected in the receptacle (because then neutral which is mistakenly hot makes ground hot) and no actual ground wire present (because then this would be a dead short).
Because of all that, tamper-resistant receptacles only protect hot and neutral. Either yours is stubborn/finicky, or it may just be broken.
Non-tamper-resistant receptacles are available, but in most places are only to be used for replacement of existing receptacles, as then the tamper-resistant part is grandfathered. (Personal note: when my electrician replaced my panels, two nearby receptacles needed to be replaced with receptacles physically next to the new panel: ordinary 120V receptacle for phone/internet/etc. and dryer. For the dryer he actually said he could put in yet another 10-30 because it is grandfathered but I took the opportunity to finally move up to a 14-30. But for the 120V receptacle it said it had to be GFCI (because laundry room) and it had to be tamper-resistant - that the inspector would reject it otherwise despite it being as much a "replacement" as the dryer receptacle.)

"I think it would require three mistakes to produce a nominally functional receptacle and also have a hot ground" – merely running a wire from the ground terminal to a bundle of hots would do the trick, wouldn't it? (I admit that that would be a rather ridiculous mistake.)

@SophieSwett No, because if you run a wire from ground to hots that will cause an immediate breaker trip, taking care of the safety problem. The problem is you don't have a real ground and combine ground with neutral (illegal but people do it to make it seem grounded) and swap hot and neutral, etc.
